# Constantly read analog in in SWITCH/CASE setup

Tags: potentiometer, switch

I'm writing a program with three different cases. Case one an LED is off, in another it is on and in the last case the brightness is controlled by a potentiometer. Each case works as I press the button. The issue I am having is with the third case. The potentiometer is read only once and the LED is set accordingly. I would like the LED to be adjusted continuously until the button is pushed again and the case is switched to off. I used the Serial.print to see the valves read from the potentiometer. I verified its only read once on each cycle through the different cases. I also changed from a SWITCH/CASE to If statements and it only reads the potentiometer once.

*CODE HAS BEEN UPDATED*

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
// BUTTON AND POT - TEST
// KNOWN ISSUE - POT ONLY TAKES ON READING
// vonderasche
// 7/28/2016
//-------------------------------------------------------

const int BUTTON_PIN = 9;
const int LED_PIN = 3;
const unsigned long DEBOUNCE_TIME = 50;

int val = 0;
int pot = 0;

int state = 0;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

bool button_press()
{
    static bool last_state;
    static unsigned long last_state_change;
    unsigned long now = millis();

    if (now - last_state_change < DEBOUNCE_TIME)
        return false;

    bool state = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
    if (state != last_state) last_state_change = now;
    bool press = last_state && !state;
    last_state = state;
    return press;
}

void loop()
{    

    unsigned long now = millis();
    static enum { OFF, ON, POT } state;

    if (button_press()) switch (state) {
    case OFF:
        analogWrite(LED_PIN, 255);
        state = ON;
        Serial.println(state);
        break;
    case ON:
        analogWrite(LED_PIN, 0);
        state = POT;
        Serial.println(state);
        break;
    case POT:
        Serial.println(state);
        int Mode = button_press();
        while (val < 1023) {
            val = (analogRead(pot) / 4);
            analogWrite(LED_PIN, val);
            Serial.println(val);
            state = OFF;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it will only go through the POT case once, if you want it to repeatedly read the potentiometer, and then change the LED brightness, you would have to put the case in a loop.

So, you might do something like this:

```
case POT:
int Mode = digitalRead(BUTTONPIN);
while(Mode == LOW) {   
    val = (analogRead(pot) / 4);
        analogWrite(LED_PIN, val);
        Serial.println(val);
        state = OFF;
        break;
        Mode = digitalRead(BUTTONPIN);
    }
}
```

If you want to use the debounce, do something like this:

```
static enum { OFF, ON, POT } state;
unsigned long now = millis();
int x = 0;

while (x == 0) {
    switch (state) {
    case OFF:
        analogWrite(LED_PIN, 255);
        if (button_press()) {
        state = ON;
        }
        break;
    case ON:
        analogWrite(LED_PIN, 0);
        if (button_press()) {
        state = POT;
        }
        break;
    case POT:
        val = (analogRead(pot) / 4);
        analogWrite(LED_PIN, val);
        Serial.println(val);
        if (button_press()) {
        state = OFF;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This should work. What it's doing is basically just going through this while loop over and over and over again, and whenever the button is pressed, THEN it will switch state, but otherwise, it'l just do the same state again and again. This way the potentiometer will work AND the debounce.

Comment: Is there another option for the while condition. I have my button press setup as a boolean function for debouncing.

Comment: You could potentially put the while switch statement in a loop. That way, it would read the whole code every time it goes through the loop, so if you press down the push button, it will switch the state, and if you don't press the push button, it will just do the same state again. That way, it WILL change the LED based on the potentiometer every time you adjust it, AND it ill work with a software debounce. Hope this helps!

Comment: Im sorry can you please be more specific. Maybe some pseudo code.

Comment: I've edited my post. Please tell me if that works, and if it doesn't, can you post the code for "button_press()" so I can understand the code better.

Comment: i updated the post with the full code I have. It was interesting to see the use of a while statement. The LED would turn on but it wouldn't cycle thru the different states when the button was pressed.